# React - Invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been troubleshooting this error for hours now.

When I use the following code, I get an error:

```
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

I have read through the linked troubleshooting page multiple times, and tried fixing all three possible causes with no success.

- I am using react 17.0.2 and react-dom 17.0.2 in my devDependencies.
- I have installed the eslint-plugin-react-hooks rule to identify if I am not using hooks correctly in my functional component.
- I have used npm ls react and npm ls react-dom to confirm I do not have duplicate react versions.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextField, Button, Typography, Paper } from '@material-ui/core';
import FileBase from 'react-file-base64';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import useStyles from './styles';
import { createPost } from '../../actions/posts';

const Form = () => {
    const [postData, setPostData] = useState({
        creator: '', title: '', message: '', tags: '', selectedFile: '',
    });
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handelSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        dispatch(createPost(postData));
    }

    const clear = () => {

    }

    return (
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <form autoComplete="off" noValidate className={`${classes.root} ${classes.form}`} onSubmit={handelSubmit}>
                <Typography variant="h6">Creating a Memory</Typography>
                <TextField name="creator" variant="outlined" label="Creator" fullWidth value={postData.creator} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, creator: e.target.value })} />
                <TextField name="title" variant="outlined" label="Title" fullWidth value={postData.title} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, title: e.target.value })} />
                <TextField name="message" variant="outlined" label="Message" fullWidth value={postData.message} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, message: e.target.value })} />
                <TextField name="tags" variant="outlined" label="Tags" fullWidth value={postData.tags} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, tags: e.target.value })} />
                <div className={classes.fileInput}>
                    <FileBase type="file" multiple={false} onDone={({base64}) => setPostData({ ...postData, selectedFile: base64})} />
                </div>
                <Button className={classes.buttonSubmit} variant="contained" color="primary" size="large" type="submit" fullWidth>Submit</Button>
                <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" size="small" onClick={clear} fullWidth>Clear</Button>
            </form>
        </Paper>
    );
}

export default Form;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid, CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Post from './Post/Post';
import useStyles from './styles';

const Posts = () => {
    const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);
    const classes = useStyles();


    return (
        !posts.length ? <CircularProgress /> : (
            <Grid className={classes.container} container alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
                {posts.map((post) => (
                    <Grid key={post._id} item xs={12} sm={6}>
                        <Post post={post} />
                    </Grid>
                ))}
            </Grid>
        )
    );
}

export default Posts;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia, Button, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import ThumbUpAltIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ThumbUpAlt';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import MoreHorizIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreHoriz';
import moment from 'moment';
import useStyles from './styles';


const Post = ({ post }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Card className={classes.card}>
            <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={post.selectedFile} title={post.title} />
            <div className={classes.overlay}>
                <Typography variant="h6">{post.creator}</Typography>
                <Typography variant="body2">{moment(post.createdAt).fromNow()}</Typography>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.overlay2}>
                <Button style={{color: 'white'}} size="small" onClick={() => {}}>
                    <MoreHorizIcon fontSize="default" />
                </Button>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.details}>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">{post.tags.map((tag) => `#${tag} `)}</Typography>
            </div>
            <CardContent>
                <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h5" gutterBottom>{post.message}</Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions className={classes.cardActions}>
                <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => {}}>
                    <ThumbUpAltIcon fontSize="small" />
                    Like
                    {post.likeCount}
                </Button>
                <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => {}}>
                    <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />
                    Delete
                </Button>
            </CardActions>
        </Card>
    );
}

export default Post;
```

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
  mainContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  smMargin: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  actionDiv: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
}));
```

Comment: The code you have shown is not where your error is coming from.

Comment: I felt I was looking in the wrong place ...
This is simply the code that appears below the error message

Comment: Show your **component** code - the one that uses the actual hook.

Comment: I edited the main post

Comment: Show your code from `./styles` - it needs to be wrapped in `makeStyles` - is it? [Like this example](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api)

Comment: `useStyles`? What is that?

Comment: @spender - it's from `material-ui`

Comment: yes it wrapped with makeStyles

Comment: Everything you've shown so far looks fine. Are you sure the error is coming from these components? e.g. If you don't render the `Posts` component, do you still see the warning?

Comment: Just want to add everything works well when there is no information in DB,
When there is information I get this fall,

Comment: In the end I found the problem, my test was not good and probably I have Duplicate React, I run "npm link ../myapp/node_modules/react" and now its work